# GODOT : can get_string_from_utf8() work with other language?

Tags: godot, gdscript

var keytyped = PoolByteArray([typedevent.unicode]).getstringfrom_utf8()

code above is working fine with english language
but its dont work with Thai language

if i typed [A] its will recognize as [A]
but if i typed [ร] (locate at [I] key) its will recognize as [#] instead of [ร]

is it a way to make it work?

Godot version v3.5.1.stable.official [6fed1ffa3]

Comment: Can you share input and output? Edit: I suspect the error is elsewhere. For example the input was not encoded correctly, or the output is being displayed with a font that does not support the characters, stuff like that.

Comment: I very much suspect the font problem. Godot only has a very basic font by default. Make sure you use a proper font stack for output. iirc the "translation demo" project shows how to set up a font stack.